# Minimum value for each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im trying to compute the minimum for each row in a pandas dataframe.

I would like to add a column that calculates the minimum values and ignores "NaN" and "WD"

For example

```
A   B   C   D
1   3   2   WD
3   WD  NaN 2
```

should give me a new column like

```
Min
1
2
```

I tried `df.where(df > 0).min(axis=1)`
and `df.where(df != "NaN").min(axis=1)` without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to numeric with non numeric to NaNs by `errors='coerce'` in [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) so is possible use `min`:

```
df['Min'] = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').min(axis=1)
print (df)
   A   B    C   D  Min
0  1   3  2.0  WD  1.0
1  3  WD  NaN   2  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

list=DataFrame.min(axis=1, skipna=[Nan,WD],numeric_only=true)

DataFrame['min']=list